# Getting RichText Area Values on javascript event

Tags: richtextarea

I have one inputfield which is bind to richtext area field. I want to check its content on KeyDown event. How can i get it? I have successfully applied jquery for text area field but it is not working for rich text area field.

Comment: Check if my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530539/document-getelementbyid-on-ck-editor-body-returning-null will help you?

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Why are you applying onkeydown with jQuery anyway? Looks like http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputTextarea.htm has an attribute for that. If it doesn't work with `richText=true` you could log a bug case with SF support.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to get the id of an apex control is:   `$('[id$="Apex_control_Id"]').event_here();`